# ¿Cómo acceder a localhost desde un dispositivo móvil?

Tags: android, mysql

En los ejemplos  que  he visto en la red me dice que  tengo que  conectarme  con la `IP` de mi PC. Localizando la `IP` de esta manera `ipconfig` dentro del `CMD`.

Me fui a la carpeta de `XAMPP` a la  carpeta `httpd-xampp.conf` y desactivé  la opción `Require local`  anteponiéndole  una `#`.

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
   <IfModule php7_module>
  <Files "webalizer.php">
    php_admin_flag safe_mode off
  </Files>
   </IfModule>
   AllowOverride AuthConfig
   #Require local
   ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Después de  todos estos  pasos  voy al navegador de  mi dispositivo móvil  poniendo  la  dirección IP de mi PC  y no consigo  conectarme al `localhost`.

¿Cómo  puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el programa **[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started)** el cual te permite abrir un servidor web que tengas de manera local al exterior.

Una vez lo hayas descargado tendrás que indicarle en que puerto está escuchando tu servidor web, que por lo general será el 80 (como utilizas XAMPP, a no ser de que se lo hayas cambiado, será el que tenga por defecto).

Para indicarle en que puerto está escuchando tu servidor web tendrás que abrir la consola de Windows e introducir el siguiente comando:

```
ngrok http 80
```

lo cual te dará algo parecido a:

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0/2.0
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80

Connnections                  ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

La url `http://92832de0.ngrok.io` (en tu caso será diferente) será la que puedas utilizar como `localhost`.

Answer (score 10):

Si ambos (el localhost y el dispositivo movil) están conectados a la misma red entonces usa tu dirección `IP` asignada por el router (no el localhost, ni 127.0.0.1)

Para encontrar tu IP:

- Abre la ventana de comandos (cmd)
- Escribe `ipconfig` (en windows) o `ifconfig` (en Unix)

Comment: ¿No es lo mismo que indica el OP en la pregunta y que es motivo de su problema? Yo también tuve problemas en el pasado con algunas redes locales y para solventarlo me sirvió el programa que indico en mi respuesta. En el resto de redes locales he podido acceder como tu dices.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero el no especifica si ambos están en la misma red, pueda que este intentando conectarse con la red de datos del dispositivo móvil. por eso hice la aclaración...

Comment: Sí, de hecho la vote positivo por eso mismo, porque realmente es así como debería de poder conectarse aunque para ciertos casos concretos de esta manera no se podrá conectar. La verdad que nunca supe como conectarme en ese tipo de redes locales hasta que me recomendaron usar el programa de abajo...

Comment: @Luis Acuña te  comento que mi dispositivo móvil y  la pc  donde  tengo  localhost están  conectados  a la misma red y no puedo acceder a  los datos, lo que si logré es  conectarme de la manera  que me  mostraron en  la  la parte  de abajo utilizando  ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

En el firewall de windows creen una nueva regla de puerto

modifiquen el requiere local del xampp.conf y agreguen esto al final del documento

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
# Close XAMPP security section here
<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:security))”>
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))”>
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me encontré ante la misma situación, después de cambiar carpetas, desactivar firewall y probar con muchas URL distintas, al final encontré que nada de esto era necesario, simplemente para conectar tu celular a tu servicio WEB corriendo en tu pc debes tener en cuenta:

**1.** Ambos deben estar conectados a la misma red, no importa si alguno está por ethernet o
wifi, es indiferente...

**2.** Debes tener tu servidor de aplicaciones corriendo, ya sea Wampp, Xampp, Laragon... (recomiendo Laragon, me parece más portable, más cómodo de usar y es más liviano que el Wampp por mucho)

**3.** Asegúrate de que al escribir localhost:(puerto donde está corriendo el servidor de aplicaciones)/(direccion a la que quieres acceder para una petición x), en tu navegador, para ver inicialmente si funciona, ya sea que deba mostrar un formato JSON o lo que sea.

**4.** En tu celular no escribas localhost, tampoco hace falta tomar en cuenta el http o https, si tu servidor de aplicaciones está corriendo en el puerto 1000 por ejemplo, basta con escribir en el navegador de tu celular (direccion_ip_computadora):(puerto_en_el_que_se_ejecuta_el_servidor_de_aplicaciones), ejemplo: 191.166.1.193:1000

**5.** A partir de ésta url, puedes trabajar con las demás funciones de la API REST o API Restful desarrollada, sería algo como: 191.166.1.193:1000/listar, 191.166.1.193:1000/eliminar/2, etc.